# Multiple Tomcat Authenticator Valves

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, tomcat-valve

Is it possible to have multiple authenticator Valves within the same Tomcat context configuration? I know you can have multiple Realms through the [`CombinedRealm`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm), but what about different authentication methods?

I have to update a web application so that it can use a new authentication source, while still using the legacy authentication source to fall back on.

Here's what I currently have in the application's context.xml:

```xml
<Context path="/myApp">
   <Valve className="com.company.NewAuthenticator"/>
   <Valve className="com.company.LegacyAuthenticator"/>

   <!-- Dummy realm to prevent pop-up window -->
   <Realm className="com.company.DummyRealm"/>
</Context>
```

It appears that `NewAuthenticator` rejects the user's request, the `LegacyAuthenticator` is never called. I guess this is expected behavior, but is there another way to make this work?

Details:

- Tomcat 6.0
- I *have* to use Authtenticators, as both custom systems set values in the HTTP Request that determine authentication success/failure and I need to create the custom Tomcat security principals to store the roles.
- Both authentication sources are custom and non-standard. I have to write my own authenticators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no `CombinedAthenticator`. You have to roll your own implementation.